# Link Bootsrap Tabs to pager (Previous Next)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab4">Tab 4</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>Tab 1</h3>
      <p>This is Tab 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Tab 2</h3>
      <p>This is Tab 2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Tab 3</h3>
      <p>This is Tab 3</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab4" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Tab 4</h3>
      <p>This is Tab 4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>                 
  <ul class="pager">
    <li><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Do you have any idea how to link a Pager to tabs in Bootstrap? The pager (Previous & Next) should take you from the active tab to the next or previous tabs? Suppose user is on tab 3 and each tab have data fields, when the user fills those fields the "Next" should allow him to continue to tab 4 otherwise the "Next" link should be disabled.

Comment: where is you javascript?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab4">Tab 4</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>Tab 1</h3>
      <p>This is Tab 1</p>
   <ul class="pager">

    <li><a href="#tab2">Next</a></li>
  </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Tab 2</h3>
      <p>This is Tab 2</p>
<ul class="pager">
    <li><a href="#tab1">Previous</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Next</a></li>
  </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Tab 3</h3>
      <p>This is Tab 3</p>
<ul class="pager">
    <li><a href="#tab2">Previous</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab4">Next</a></li>
  </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="tab4" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Tab 4</h3>
      <p>This is Tab 4</p>
<ul class="pager">
    <li><a href="#tab3">Previous</a></li>
  </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>                 

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `next()/prev()` and `tab('show')`

```js
$('.prev').click(function(){
  $('.nav-tabs .active').prev().tab('show');//get the next tab and show it
});

$('.next').click(function(){
  $('.nav-tabs .active').next().tab('show');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab4">Tab 4</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>Tab 1</h3>
      <p>This is Tab 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Tab 2</h3>
      <p>This is Tab 2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Tab 3</h3>
      <p>This is Tab 3</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab4" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Tab 4</h3>
      <p>This is Tab 4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>                 
  <ul class="pager">
    <li><a href="#" class="prev">Previous</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="next">Next</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```